# Bluetooth detection via webpage

Tags: mobile, bluetooth

Does anyone have a script (or know if it is possible) to detect bluetooth via a webpage (without knowing beforehand if the device viewing the page has bluetooth).

What I'd like to do is check for bluetooth and poll for nearby devices.

Can this be done? Or could it be done if you knew what device someone was using? ie. is it OS dependent?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this from a webpage, without the help of some sort of browser plugin.

Besides, I would have serious issues with a site that tried to "poll for nearby [bluetooth] devices" whenever I visited it...